# Copy array of structs into buffer and vice-verca

Tags: c

I'm not very familiar with C, hence the question. I have an array of structs and each struct contains a heap-allocated array of its own, e.g.,

```
struct Foo {
 int a;
 int b;
 void* ptr; // heap allocated (size known)
 int size_of_ptr; 
 double d;
};
```

Now the question is how can I copy the array of Foos into a heap allocated buffer, and then pass that buffer into some method which then recreates the original array of Foo objects? I need this for serialization/deserialization of the array of Foo objects.

A small example to illustrate the point:

```
void bar(int n_objs_) {

 Foo* f_arr = (Foo) malloc(sizeof Foo * n_objs_);

 for (int i=0; i<n_objs_; ++i) {

    f_arr[i].ptr = allocate(someSize); /* some method that allocates on heap */
    f_arr[i].a = i;
    f_arr[i].size_of_ptr = someSize;
    // ... ditto for other members as well
 }

  void* buf = serialize(f_arr, n_objs_); // how?
  Foo* new = deserialize(buf); // how?
}
```

Im confused on how to mem copy the array into some allocated buffer knowing that each objects (Foo) contains an array (ptr) which is allocated on heap. Deserialization is also bugging me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Serialization and deserialization is rather complex and far from trivial. If you can, I suggest you find some third-party serialization library to help you, especially if you want generic serialization (i.e. not only for one or two specific structures).

Comment: If you want to serialize the objects, the pointer `void* ptr;` is not sufficient. You also need either the size of the allocated memory or an algorithm to determine the size from the data if this is possible. If you only want to serialize a single type of data structure you can implement it on your your own. You should [edit] your question make your requirements clear about the serialized data and how you might want process them between `serialize` and `deserialize` and if you want to serialize more than one structure.

Comment: @Bodo yes, I know the size of the void* ptr, I will edit the structure. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You will need to define what the serialized buffer contents should look like. In general the serialized version should not contain any pointers, but it could contain offsets relative to some other point in the buffer.

Comment: What kind of data is contained in the memory pointed by `ptr`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky some other object data